# Want a wireless device which can catch Wifi signals and beam it again and also pass internet through ethernet cable to desktop

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I want a networking device which can catch a poor Wi-fi internet connection from one of my rooms, beam it again through its own Wi-fi and through the ethernet cable pass the internet connection to the desktop PC. Also I want that if I want to connect to internet, I can just connect to this networking device.

I found one D-Link DAP-1360 but not sure whether it would serve all the purposes.

I am looking for the terminology for the device I'm searching. Also will be of great help if suitable devices across different brands can also be suggested.

Thanks

Comment: Not a product recommendation site as brand and model suggestions go stale pretty immediately. Questions on how the devices work, what they are or how to set them up are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a **WiFi Extender**. It works by receiving the signal from the Wireless router and retransmitting it local to the extender's position.

Plug the unit into a wall power socket in an intermediate location where it gets a good signal from the router. Use two if you have a long distance between the router and the final location where you want internet access.

They also have ethernet jacks on them so you can use a wired connection to a computer or printer that doesn't have WiFi built in.

Here's one manufacturer's version with internal patch antenna, they also can come with high-gain external antennas, just make sure the one you're considering has 1 or 2 ethernet jacks.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is the Wi-fi extender different from Wi-fi repeater? Also when I went to the market for this issue, the shopkeeper showed me D-Link DAP 1360 Wireless and Access point device. Will this device solve the issue?
Kindly note that the device should also be able to share the desktop folders connected to it via the ethernet.

Comment: Extender, repeater are the same idea. [D-Link Wireless Range Extender](http://us.dlink.com/products/access-points-range-extenders-and-bridges/wireless-n-range-extender/) From the website, that's its purpose. As to sharing folders, that is a router firewall and workstation setup which will have security issues. Windows shares allowed on the internet tend to be a bad idea and are topic for another question that needs to be asked => (How do I share desktop folders with this router?). The extender only allows extending the signal range, not firewalling.

Comment: Some third party firmware also supports this kind of setup. http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Repeater_Bridge